# Как получить ID страницы архива?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Использую ACF. Нужно вывести значение с поля two_cols_catalog_left вот так

```
the_field('two_cols_catalog_left', $page_id);
```

Где $page_id это ID страницы архива. И получить этот ID мне нужно вне цикла.
Делал так

```
echo get_queried_object_id();
```

не получается.
Как можно получить ID текущей страницы архива archive.php ?

Comment: А что выдает метод `get_queried_object_id` и почему не получается?

Comment: что значит "Как можно получить ID текущей страницы архива archive.php " ? она уже по определению не страница. Вы можете получить айди объекта или же в цикле получить айди постов

Answer (score 0):

У архива нет ID, можно узнать что это архив с помощью функции

```php
is_post_type_archive( 'product' )
```